# Confirmation message doesn't show up in firefox web browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

I am using script which I found in the internet to generate my confirmation message whenever user try to leave page without submitting form after changes.

There is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var formSubmitting = false;
  var setFormSubmitting = function() { formSubmitting = true; };

    var _isDirty = false;
    var setDirtyField = function() { _isDirty = true; }
    window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = 'Nepamirškite užpildyti užduoties žurnalo! ';
        //confirmationMessage += 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

        if (formSubmitting || !_isDirty) {
            return undefined;
        }
        else{
            (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
            return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.  
        }

    });
};
</script>
```

That's what I see in google chrome with this script:
[image]

And that's what I see with the same code in firefox web browser:
[image]

Any idea how to add mine text to firefox confirmation message? Replacing exist text with mine would be perfect.

Comment: Do you mean Firefox?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. Isn't it the same?

Comment: Ok my bad, in my country everyone calls it mozilla for a no reason. Mozilla is just a company whom created firefox...

Comment: The problem is that they also created Mozilla Suite (which is a browser but is ancient, no longer supported, and bug ridden), FirefoxOS, Thunderbird and various others. It's also weird to call one browser after the company that made it but not do the same for Microsoft, Google, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> In Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." See [bug 588292](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292).

You can't override the default text.

Comment: I ran into the problem that firefox warns about data not saved before submitting the form when chrome doesn't. It annoys because data must be saved after this post and there is no reason to warn.